# Datepicker price calculation discount

Tags: jquery, datepicker, discount

I'm using jquery datepicker to calculate price according to selected date. Now it's set 125 for one month. I want to make a discount 5% if customer chooses 3 months period and 10% if customers chooses 4+ months.

How to do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/5BbGS/502/

```
    function showDays() {
    var start = $('#arr_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#dep_date').datepicker('getDate');
    if (!start || !end) return;
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    var dayss = days*4.166666666666667;
    dayss = dayss.toFixed(0);
    $('#num_nights').val(dayss);
}

$("#arr_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays,
     onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
         var dParts = selectedDate.split('-');
         var in30Days = new Date(dParts[2] + '/' +
                        dParts[1] + '/' +
                        (+dParts[0] + 30)
               );

    $( "#dep_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", in30Days );
    }
});
$("#dep_date").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    onSelect: showDays,

});
```

Thank you guys!

Comment: fiddle not working..

Comment: for one month how much discount you are giving

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/x3n3ftwc/1/ ..?

Comment: for one month I'm giving none of discount. Discount should be counted if it is selected 90 or more days. As I imagine 5% discount for 90-120 days, 10% discount for 121+ days.

Comment: whats the last text field for ?

Comment: are you using this for calculating price `var dayss = days*4.166666666666667` or is it for some other purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function...

```
function showDays() {
    var start = $('#arr_date').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#dep_date').datepicker('getDate');
    if (!start || !end) return;
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    var dayss = days*4.166666666666667;
    dayss = dayss.toFixed(0);
    if(days>90 && days<=120) dayss = dayss*95/100;
    if(days>120) dayss = dayss*90/100;
    $('#num_nights').val(dayss);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5BbGS/507/

But i guess 3 months doesn't means 90 days, you need to look into it...

Here is a function to get the number of months between two dates:

```
function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() ;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5BbGS/514/

Comment: Damn... You're right. Maybe you have any suggestions?

Comment: @void : i dont know if he can upvote you he dont have sufficient points but he can accept your answer

Comment: up vote his question first if you think it is beneficial